# text not centered with background color

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

so i have created this flexbox container with some flex-items:

so what i have is when i press on overview or alerts, it doesn't have this white border background color, when i press on one of them it will trigger a class called .selected and will color the background in white.

the problem is when i press on one of them the white border is not spamming the entire width ( from start to end) also the text inside the background is not centered in the middle when i press it and i don't know why

code:

```
<div className="container">
            <div className="flex-item item-1 item">John Smith</div>
            <div className="flex-item item-2 item">Male, 26 years old</div>
            <div className='flex-item item-3 item'onClick={setSelectedItem} style={style} > Overview</div>
            <div className='flex-item item-4 item'onClick={setSelectedItem} style={style}>Alerts</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

css code:

```
.container {
    border: 2px solid #57c0e8;
    background-color: #57c0e8;
    margin-top: 5%;
    float: left;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    color:white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height:40rem;
    width:15rem;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    font-size:0.9rem;
}

.flex-item{
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

.selected{
    background-color: white;
    color: #57c0e8;
    border-radius: 50px 0 0 50px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px lightgray;
    width: 14rem;
    height: 5%;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want the white part where it says "Overview" to have the text centerent vertically. 
If this is the case, I would give your `.selected` element `display:flex; align-items:center;` . For the part with the width of it, seems like you have a cointainer that has a fixed width. As we dont have a codepen, I can't say for sure, but I think that width is the problem. Try removing it , and give all items but that "Overview" a padding left. Tell me what happens after you do it.

Would like me some codepen.

Comment: It's better to add `align-items: center` to whole `.flex-item`, because it will move when class will be added

Comment: the first part works great to center the elements i added display and align to .selected and it works great. for the second part, yes i have fixed width for the container thats because i want it to have a fixed width not be so big but the elements inside to be colored in white background all the way from start to end:
this is the code pen i don't know how to set it using react so i just put the entire code:
https://codepen.io/mouhamadibra/pen/OJyered

Answer (score 0):

To center (vertically) text inside, just add `align-items: center` to `.flex-item`:

```
.flex-item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

And to be full width, change to `width: 100%` on `.selected`

Comment: You'd need to add ```display: flex``` for this to work

Answer (score 0):

for `.selected`, remove `border-radius` and make `width:100%`

Comment: why remove `border-radius`? It's not necessary, it does nothing for width or aligning text

Comment: adds a circular crop which results in the white background to not start from one edge to the other